# how to use less to set a background colour

Tags: css, less

In my Page I have the following:

`<div class="col-md-12 @project.ColourCode">
   <div class="dropzone">`

The div on this area of the page has the backround colour set to the value of ColourCode when rendered typically Red,Green or Amber. These are droppable zone's for drag and drop functionality. I'm using Less and I want to make a class that will set the ColourCode div say 50% less than it's current colour.

So backup in my less file I have declared a variable:

```
@default-backcolour : background-color;
```

Now I have 2 issues. The first is if I declare something like:

```
.droppable-hover {

background-color : lighten(@default-backcolour,50%);}
```

Less gives a compilation error, so how do I lighten since I thought lighten was a function of Less. Second because I'm dropping in the 'dropzone class, the parent div doesn't get completely masked by the .droppable-hover class.

Comment: The value for the `@default-backcolour` variable is wrong. What does `background-color` refer to?

Comment: The Less `lighten` function will work only when a color is supplied to the function. If you are trying to lighten the current background-color by giving the value as `background-color` then it **will not work** because Less compiler has no way of knowing what the current background color is.

Comment: I haven't tested it, but to @Harry's comment, maybe `lighten(inherit,50%)` might work?

Comment: background-color isn't known at compile time. It gets set at runtime when the page renders. i just tried @Alexander suggestion and it gives me a compile error.

Comment: @Alexander: No, the Less compiler will accept only a real color for that function and not any keywords.

Comment: @bilpor: How is the `background-color` set to the `@project.ColourCode`? Is that done by creating CSS classes (or) is it directly set via inline styles using JS (or some backend script)?

Comment: @Harry it's injected in via a property on a viewModel (MVC)

Comment: I thought I might be able to do: `.if (.dropzone, background-color, green) { background-color : yellow; }` as an example,but no joy

Comment: using chrome developer tools I have managed to get to the point that if I do the following : `$(this).data(this).parent().attr('class')` then this returns me **"col-md-12 Red"** how now do I change Red to say Yellow